Could someone add CQG for questions as a tag as I cant
Please could someone add CQG for questions as a tag as I cant.
Can someone add the tag CQG at stackoverflow? I don't have enough reputation yet to add the tag. See question below
https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/14211/cqg-api-solutions-to-execute-orders-monitor-positions-and-rebalance-based-on-ca
Thanks
Robert

I did a search on QuantSE for questions regarding CQG and got 4 hits, included your latest question, which was closed by a fellow moderator.
I am not going to debate on whether or not it should have been clod and for what exact reason but, the fact that you were asking for contact details clearly suggests that you are new to StackExchange and you need to get to know how to work with Q/A sites, such as this one. See the faqs for more information.
Regarding the tag, we see them as a way to organize questions roughly speaking, or to group certain questions together.
Usually, to decide whether a badge is needed, we would look at how many existing questions would have been willing to have this tag.
As I said, searching for CQG returns only 4 hits, which is obvisouly too small to justify the creation of the tag.
